# Here Javascript map library not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, here-api

Background: I'm building a small map component in a larger web page which is in react to display an area around a location.

Problem: I've run into an issue where the following component will retrieve the tiles it requires (I can see it in the network usage), create the component, and then render the map in 270x0, making it not visible. Below is the code I'm using for the component.

What I've tried: If I manually re-size the the component to 270x250 I can see the background UI and Behaviors work correctly and render appropriately. I've confirmed that the tiles the library pulls are relevant to the area being requested and my keys are working properly. I also tried (briefly) importing the map render as a script into react and running it, but that went poorly and I would really prefer not to do approach the problem that way.

For reference I'm going off of [this tutorial here](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/maps/map-at-specified-location) which I'm adapting to be in react.

```
 var Map = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      target: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
                         app_id: keys.app_id,
                         app_code: keys.app_code,
                         useCIT: true,
                         useHTTPS: true
                       });

      var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
      var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                          defaultLayers.normal.map,{
                            center: {lat:this.props.target.lat,
                                     lng:this.props.target.long},
                            zoom: 13
                          });

      var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
      var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Location</p>
          <div id="map" styles="position:absolute; width:49%; height:100%; background:grey"/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

Thank you!

Update: When I manually re-size the canvas of the here API map container (from its original size of 270x1), I am able to get the top row of tiles to display. My hunch is only the top ones are displayed because originally it is only as tall as one pixel.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by setting height in pixels and with default position - static.

```
<div id="map" styles="width:500px; height:100%; background:grey"/>
```